# How to validate custom AOP annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a custom annotation as follows

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Testable {
    int index();
}
```

I define a Aspect to wrap around the actual method call

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestableAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)")
    public Object invokeAndLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Testable annotation) throws Throwable {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

The usage of the annotation is as shown below

```
@Testable(index = 1)
public void realMethod() {
    //some code here
}
```

This works fine so far and I can implement my login within TestableAspect#invokeAndLog.

Now I have a need to validate that the value of index is not greater than 10 for eg.

I can do this at runtime by changing aspect implementation as follows

```
    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)")
    public Object invokeAndLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Testable annotation) throws Throwable {
        if(annotation.index() > 10){
          throw new IllegalStateException("blah");
        }
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
```

But this requires that the API is invoked at-least once and its not very efficient.
Is there a way i can do this at startup of the spring boot application ?

Comment: You could write an annotation processor https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder

Comment: I wanted to suggest the same as Simon. This might not be an option, if annotations can be used in module outside the control of the OP's own build process, though. Which approach should be chosen also depends on how static or dynamic the real-life condition to check on the annotation condition actually is. If e.g. it is always `> 10`, then validation can be done at a more central point. If the condition changes depending on application state, the aspect might actually be the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would write an annotation processor or classloader to validate the annotation. Otherwise, you could try using reflection as follows:

```java
new org.reflection.Reflections("your.desired.package")
  .getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Testable.class)
  .stream()
  .map(method -> AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(method, Testable.class))
  .forEach(annotation -> {
    if (annotation.index() > 10)
      throw new IllegalStateException("blah");
  });
```

Such code can be added to a static block on any class or if you want to involve spring, just add it to a [start-up runner](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring).

Such suggestion is not ideal and comes with a price of scanning the classpath but can work!

Comment: Probably you mean `getMethodsAnnotatedWith` rather than `getFieldsAnnotatedWith`, don't you? Thanks for the Baeldung link, BTW. The article provides a great overview.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You're very welcome :)